# Why I see two API requests with different times in NextJS 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have `BuildingInfo` component where it contains API request function `getData()`:

```
import { getData } from "./api"
import { Form } from "./components/Form"
import styles from "./style.module.css"
import { Suspense } from "react"

export const BuildingInfoForm = async () => {
  const data = await getData()

  return (
    <div className={styles["container"]}>
      <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading feed...</p>}>
        <Form data={data} />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When NextJS render the component, I see two API calls at different times! What does it mean each one of them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first call shown in the pic (`*/building-info`) is the request made to the api
2. The second call shown (notice that its a child of the first call) is the request made from the api (meaning `*/building-info` made a request to second api `credium-api.*`)

---

To clarify further,

1. `components/form/building-info` is the route where your form resides.
2. On visiting that page, the component made a request to `credium-api.*` through `getData()` function (which will be a child request of `components/form/building-info`).

Comment: But I have only one call API which the second one.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin Have updated my answer. Does that clarify?

Comment: So the first one is related to the UI routing while the second is related to the API request right? But why it's `893ms`?

Comment: Thats probably because that includes all the server rendering, and the api call inside it as well.